# How to test function within directive link

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a directive for which i am trying to write some unit test for:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    transclude: true,
    template:   '<ul>' +
                    '<li ng-show="vm.hideItem">Home</li>' +
                    '<li ng-show="vm.hideItem">Products</li>' +
                    '<li ng-show="!vm.hideItem">Cart</li>' +
                    '<li ng-show="vm.hideItem">Contact Us</li>' +
                '</ul>',  
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, vm) {

        function getData(index) {
            if (index){
                vm.hideItem = true
            }
            else {
                var li = element.find("li");
                li.attr("context-driven", "");
            }
        }

        function getIndex(){
            index = myService.getIndex();
            getData(index);
        }

        getIndex();

    },
    controller: function(){}
};
```

I have the following, which pass:

```
describe('<-- myDirective Spec ------>', function () {

    var scope, $compile, element, myService;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('MyApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _myService_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $compile = _$compile_;
        myService = _myService_;

        var html = '<my-directive></my-directive>';
        element = $compile(angular.element(html))(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should return an unordered list', function () {
        var ul = element.find('ul');
        expect(ul).toBeDefined();
    });
```

How can i test the call of `getIndex`, `getData` and ensure `myService` has been called?

Comment: It is not possible to do what you're asking without refactoring the code. Again, it is testability reasons that should define the way the code is written, not vice versa. Test-unfriendly code won't get 100% test coverage (testing myService.getIndex call is all that could be done here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to successful directive testing is moving all view-related logic to controller, i.e.

```
    this.getIndex = function () {
        index = myService.getIndex();
        getData(index);
    }
```

After the element was compiled in spec, the controller instance can be retrieved and spied with

```
var ctrl = element.controller('myDirective');
spyOn(ctrl, 'getIndex').and.callThrough();
```

The good thing about writing specs is that they show design flaws. In current case it is DOM manual operation in `getData`. It is not clear from the code what `context-driven` attribute is for, but the same thing has to be achieved in Angular (data binding) and not jQuery (DOM manipulation) fashion in order to be test-friendly.